# Send Order confirmation after only order success or failed Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

Magento 2 is sending order confirmation email right once you click on place order button even if you cancel the payment. If you are using any SMS service it will send order success SMS too. This is not a good idea. What i want i need order success and SMS notification only once after if payment success or failed. Anyone can help me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: For Order email we have followed this and written blog on our experience, may be helpful https://magecomp.com/blog/send-order-confirmation-email-after-successful-payment-magento-2/

Comment: I am also facing same problem . Could you please  suggest some solution ?

Comment: Use this free extension http://magecomp.com/magento-2-order-confirmation-email.html